# regexp to split a string using comma(,) delimiter but ignore if the comma is in curly braces{,}

Tags: php, preg-split

I need a regexp to split a string using comma(,) delimiter but ignore if the comma is in curly braces{,} in the example below;

```
"asd", domain={"id"="test"}, names={"index"="user.all", "show"="user.view"}, test="test"
```

**INTO** ( IT SHOULD BE)

```
"asd"
domain={"id"="test"}
names={"index"="user.all", "show"="user.view"}
test="test"
```

**PROBLEM:** (NOT THIS)

```
"asd"
domain={"id"="test"}
names={"index"="user.all"
"show"="user.view"}
test="test"
```

I **tried** this but it also splits comma inside braces {,}

```
\{[^}]*}|[^,]+
```

But I am totally clueless as to how this should pretty much end up.
Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see to possibilities *(that don't crash with a long string)*:

The first with `preg_match_all`:

```
$pattern = '~
(?:
    \G(?!\A), # contigous to the previous match, not at the start of the string
  |           # OR
    \A ,??    # at the start of the string or after the first match when
              # it is empty
)\K           # discard characters on the left from match result
[^{,]*+       # all that is not a { or a ,
(?:
    {[^}]*}? [^{,]* # a string enclosed between curly brackets until a , or a {
                    # or an unclosed opening curly bracket until the end
)*+
~sx';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $m))
    print_r($m[0]);
```

The second with `preg_split` and backtracking control verbs to avoid parts enclosed between curly brackets *(shorter, but less efficient with long strings)*:

```
$pattern = '~{[^}]*}?(*SKIP)(*F)|,~';
print_r(preg_split($pattern, $str));
```

`(*F)` forces the pattern to fail and `(*SKIP)` forces the regex engine to skip parts already matched when the pattern fails.

The weakness of this last approach is that the pattern starts with an alternation. This means that for each character that is not a `{` or a `,`, the two branches of the alternation are tested *(for nothing)*. However, you can improve the pattern with the `S` (study) modifier:

```
$pattern = '~{[^}]*}?(*SKIP)(*F)|,~S';
```

or you can write it without an alternation, like this:

```
$pattern = '~[{,](?:(?<={)[^}]*}?(*SKIP)(*F))?~';
```

In this way, positions with a `{` or `,` are searched before with a faster algorithm than the normal walk of the regex engine.

Comment: I am going to ask one more thing, since you seem to be pretty good at regexp, if you dont mind answering.... How can I exclude?                      names={"index"="user.all", "show"="user.view"}          FROM            "asd", domain={"id"="test"}, names={"index"="user.all", "show"="user.view"}, test="test"   ={} braces form should be ignored and rest parsed by comma delimiter

Comment: @Oguzhan: what you ask is out of the scope of regex, you need to use a SQL parser.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex for splitting

```
(,)(?=(?:[^}]|{[^{]*})*$)
```

So using `preg_split` you can do it like as

```
echo preg_split('/(,)(?=(?:[^}]|{[^{]*})*$)/',$your_string);
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/pU0lU6/1)